# Trying to GET Api without Post

Tags: c#, .net, api

Im trying to develop an Api that Gets info from GitHub's API and than put those selected informations on my page as a JSON. First i did only a Console App to request the info and it's working fine - I can get all the information i need.
I never did work with APIs though, im not sure how to follow up. The main goal is to have this information consumed through a GET request.

My code right now is like this:

```
private static List<Info> infos = new List<Info>();

    public List<Info> Get()
    {
        Post();
        return infos;
    }

    public void Post()
    {

        try
        {
            GetData().Wait();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error" + e);
        }

    }


    public static async Task<string> GetData()
    {
        var url = "https://api.github.com/users/MatheusReimer/repos?sort=created&direction=desc";
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", @"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10; Win64; x64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0");
            Console.WriteLine(client.BaseAddress);
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
            string strResult = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            JToken token = JArray.Parse(strResult);
            dynamic ResultArray = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(strResult);

            //TESTING -------- var description = ResultArray[0].description;
            List<Info> jsonobj = new List<Info> { };
            foreach (dynamic array in ResultArray)
            {
                Info a = new Info();
                a.Description = array.description;
                a.CreatedAt = array.created_at;
                a.Language = array.language;
                a.ImageLocatedAt = array.owner.avatar_url;
                a.Title = array.name;
                jsonobj.Add(a);

            }
            Console.WriteLine(jsonobj.Count);
            int repoCounter = 0;
            for (int i = (jsonobj.Count - 1); i > 0; i--)
            {
                if (jsonobj[i].Language == "C#" && repoCounter <= 2)
                {
                    //Console.WriteLine($"\nData: {jsonobj[i].CreatedAt} \nDescricao: {jsonobj[i].Description} \nImage located at: {jsonobj[i].ImageLocatedAt}\nTitle: {jsonobj[i].Title}\n\n\n");
                    Info grabedInfo = new Info();
                    grabedInfo.Description = jsonobj[i].Description;
                    grabedInfo.CreatedAt = jsonobj[i].CreatedAt;
                    grabedInfo.Language = jsonobj[i].Language;
                    grabedInfo.ImageLocatedAt = jsonobj[i].ImageLocatedAt;
                    grabedInfo.Title = jsonobj[i].Title;
                    infos.Add(grabedInfo);
                    repoCounter++;
                }
            }

            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonobj);


            return strResult;
        }
    }
```

But this obviosly does not work, what's the best way to go now?

Comment: Can you clarify why you think you need POST endpoint at all?

Comment: Sure, I need to integrate my API to a Chat Bot that will use those informations. I know i could just use the github api to do so but I'm purposely overcomplicating to test the API functionalities. As I said, I don't have much knowledge of Api's, I'm testing everything I can do with them.

Comment: Okay, but HTTP POST methods have a function body with user-provided data. For example, if you wanted to have some `"api.github.com/users/" + username + "/repos"`, but since you dont, you should only call `GetData()` in your server's GET method call, then remap the `Task<string>` result into `List<Info>` like you expect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two server HTTP methods should not call each other. This violates the Single-Responsibility Principle, and goes against the pattern of MVVM/MVC frameworks, such as those implemented in .NET

---

That being said, you don't need a POST for the shown example.

First, make your method actually return the correct values

```
public static async List<Info> GetData() { 
   ...
   List<Info> jsonobj = new List<Info> { };
   ...
   return jsonobj;
}
```

Then change your server to use that

```
public List<Info> Get()
{
    return GetData();
}
```

I'd also suggest relocating your "business-logic" code away from your "controller", and instead inject it via a constructor. [Refer here for ASP.NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: Thank you very much, I believe I won't be able to do it exactly the way you mentioned because I need to return a Task since the function is asynchronous. But I will try to find a solution, again thanks for the clarification.

Comment: You should be able to have something like `return await GetData()`, but `GetData()` is going to be blocking anyway, so there is no reason to define it as `async`, other than the fact that you're using `client.GetAsync`

Comment: Im not sure if anyone else is stuck on a problem like this but i will put the resolution here anyway. I did the way  you said @OneCricketeer, just had to change the "Get" to async aswell and put getData as :

       `private static async Task<List<Info>> GetData()`

I will try to improve my business-logic now as you commented.